# Remove Android app border with FireMonkey

Tags: android, delphi, border, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I create an Android app with FireMonkey (10.2.2), but I don't understand why I have a top and right white border. I never added that to my app.

I started to create an example app, just a black form with a black TRectangle without sides.

I don't have to code anything, just design. When I compile for Windows, it's OK. I have this border only on Android.

I get this result:

[image]

You can download the example project here : [Click Here to Download](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/7f0eb3a27b4ac3c40b5684041a85c02820191031091655/2bedbd52e472002931cb734ab4e6337620191031091655/cb9112)

Answer (score 2):

I was having the exact same problem when adding a `TStyleBook`, but I found a workaround. The steps are the following:

1. Click on the form (I've done it in the Master view, of course)
2. Go to the Properties tab, then open `Fill` > `Color`
3. Choose your desired color, you can copy it from the style you imported for the `TStyleBook` (In my case it was: `#FF2B3840` from the `backgroundstyle` setting in the style)
4. Within `Fill` also change the `Kind` to the value `Solid`

Basically, this workaround is about manually overriding the inherited style from `TStyleBook`. I know this is not ideal because it's a hardcoded value you'll have to keep track of if you ever change styles at runtime in your app.

Source link #1: [Click here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Working_with_Native_and_Custom_FireMonkey_Styles#To_add_a_custom_style_to_a_FireMonkey_multi-device_application).
Source link #2: [Click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ayJprtKhH9Q).
Source link #3: [Click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9XxM7W94p4).