# How to get rid of the line between the StatusBar and the Form in FMX?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I applied a new color to the StatusBar to match the color of the Form. But this thin line has appeared and I can't get rid of it.

```
TAndroidHelper.Activity.getWindow.setStatusBarColor($FF0060C7);
```

I tried to change the border style, apply a TRectangle with contents align, but nothing works.

[image: Line in detail view]

Comment: Is the line visible in the IDE (when designing), or only on an actual device at run time? Please show a [mre] including the `.fmx` file. And please keep it minimal.

Comment: What version of Delphi did you use ? That’s remember me this point https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640154/remove-android-app-border-with-firemonkey